# Returning key/value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a javascript program, whhich requires to store the original value of array of numbers and the doubled values in a key/value pair. I am beginner in javascript. Here is the program:

```
var Num=[2,10,30,50,100];
var obj = {};

function my_arr(N)  
{
    original_num = N
    return original_num;

}



function doubling(N_doubled)
{
   doubled_number = my_arr(N_doubled);

   return doubled_number * 2;
}   


for(var i=0; i< Num.length; i++)
 {
    var original_value = my_arr(Num[i]);
    console.log(original_value);
    var doubled_value = doubling(Num[i]);
    obj = {original_value : doubled_value};
console.log(obj);
}
```

The program reads the content of an array in a function, then, in another function, doubles the value.

My program produces the following output:

```
2
{ original_value: 4 }
10
{ original_value: 20 }
30
{ original_value: 60 }
50
{ original_value: 100 }
100
{ original_value: 200 }
```

The output which I am looking for is like this:

```
{2:4, 10:20,30:60,50:100, 100:200}
```

What's the mistake I am doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your goal is to enrich the `obj` map with new properties in order to get `{2:4, 10:20,30:60,50:100, 100:200}`. But instead of doing that you're replacing the value of the `obj` variable with an object having only one property.

Change

```
obj = {original_value : doubled_value};
```

to

```
obj[original_value] = doubled_value;
```

And then, at the end of the loop, just log

```
console.log(obj);
```

Here's the complete loop code :

```
for(var i=0; i< Num.length; i++) {
    var original_value = my_arr(Num[i]);
    var doubled_value = doubling(original_value);
    obj[original_value] = doubled_value;
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use an expression as a label in an *Object* literal, it doesn't get evaluated. Instead, switch to bracket notation.

```
var original_value = my_arr(Num[i]),
    doubled_value = doubling(Num[i]);
obj = {}; // remove this line if you don't want object to be reset each iteration
obj[original_value] = doubled_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
//Original array
var Num=[2,10,30,50,100];
//Object with original array keys with key double values
var obj = myFunc(Num);
//Print object
console.log(obj);


function myFunc(arr)
{
    var obj = {};
    for (var i in arr) obj[arr[i]] = arr[i] * 2;
    return obj;
}
```